# iOS app freezes during background execution

Tags: ios, objective-c, background, location, freeze

I have an app with background location and fetch modes activated.
It gets user location, send it to server, read the results (JSON) and fires a local notification.
This process has been tested every 15, 60 and 180 seconds on an iPhone 4S.

Here comes the problem.

If the app goes in background, after about 3 minutes, it freezes and stop its communication with server. I can see that from Xcode, in debug navigator: memory is allocated, but CPU and energy impact are zero.
This problem can be replicated opening a heavy app like Youtube: in this case the app freezes after few seconds.
Most likely iOS itself freezes the app.
My question is: is there any way to prevent this freeze or to unfreeze the app without resuming it?

Comment: You have already opted for location update background mode, your app will 'unfreeze' and once the user changes his location :) Location delegates gets called everytime user changes his location based on the distance filter you have specified :) In the location update delegate you can use NSURLSession and session manager to communicate with your server. If you need frequent invocation of your app set the distance to most accurate filter. Using location is always a trade off remember your app may drain out user's battery :) Use it only as per your needs

Answer (score 0):

plz use this code

set setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates property of your location manger

```
if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:)]) {
            [self.locationManager setAllowsBackgroundLocationUpdates:YES];
        }
```

you can also check background remming time

```
 NSLog(@"%f",[UIApplication sharedApplication].backgroundTimeRemaining);
```